# Relative size header using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have designed the header with the following CSS:

```
.Navigation { height: 84px; background: url(../images/Navigation.png) repeat-x; border-bottom: 1px solid #919191; }

#NavigationInside { padding-left: 15px; width: 945px; margin: 0 auto; }
```

This is fixed height and width header whereas I want it relative to the screen size. Both end of the header should touch the left and right corner of the screen.

Please help me out to make changes in the CSS.

Comment: Could you make a [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) of your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.Navigation { 
  width:100%; 
  margin:0; 
  padding:0; 
  ...
```

Comment: If this didn't work, then you either have a problem with your HTML, or you need to work on the width:945px in #NavigationInside, it may be wider than the screen size.